# my flutter app is unable to get or post https request

Tags: android, flutter, debugging, https

I am building a flutter app, everything is alright if I use http requests but when it come to https, I am unable to get or post https request, debugger gives no error, even it does not print response of the request. I tried,  `flutter clean` and rebuild app so many times even clearing my mobile device cache etc. it does not work
I am working and testing on android device

**Code**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

var url = Uri.parse('https://my.api-end-point.com:port/auth');

Map requestHeaders = <String, String>{
  'Content-type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': 'application/json'
};
Map body = <String, String>{'email': email, "password": password};
var response = await http.post(url, headers: requestHeaders, body: json.encode(body));
var res = jsonDecode(response.body);
print(res);
```

** Test **
working also on postman

[image]
any help will be appreciated!

Comment: both http and https URLs are working, I have confirmed on postman

Comment: Thank you guys, problem solved! actually problem was with API server's SSL certificate.

Comment: as im backend devloper so i faced same problem. How you solved this Question ?  and  `actually problem was with API server's SSL certificate.` how you do that?

Comment: @khush, I just added configure SSL certificate on my API server that was expired.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried hitting the same api using postman?
may be there is an issue with the api itself since the console returns no errors

Comment: yes! I have tried working on postman for both http and https,